# Finding the magnitude of $\vec{F}$

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

[image]

The object with the weight of $80N$ is balanced in the force of $\vec{F}$. So, I want to find the magnitude of $\vec{F}$.

Assuming that the object is in equilibrium, then we have

$$F\sin{37} - 80 = 0$$

Which gives

$$F\sin37=80$$

Thereby, we get

$$F = \dfrac{80}{\sin 37} = \dfrac{80}{0.6} = 133.33N$$

Am I right?

Regards!

Comment: This looks totally fine

Comment: Is the rope that carries $\vec F$ attached to the ceiling? If so, the force counter-balancing the the $80$N weight is $F\sin{37^{\circ}} + F$ because of the tension in the rope.

Comment: @James I thought so :) Why John? Or do you see anything unclear in the question?

Comment: I'm really getting too many answers from different people. The fact that there should be anything going wrong with this question. It's impossible that everyone finds anohter answer. Perhaps I should have mentioned something concerning to the diagram or question. Could you please explain why people give anohter answers?

Comment: @Busi Draw a free body diagram of the pulley. There are four forces acting on it, not three. You should get about $50$N as an answer.

Comment: I think the confusion is due to the drawing, since there seem to be two ropes (one directly connected to the sealing and one on which we exert the force $\vec{F}$. However, the way I read the exercise, there is just a force $\vec{F}$ on the rope with a magnitude of 133.33$N$. If you are still in doubt, though, I would advise to ask your insturctor

Comment: @James The horizontal rope is attached to the pulley and the vertical rope goes around the pulley.

Comment: @JohnDouma Ahh now I get the total picture. In that case, the answer below seems correct

Comment: @James How should I edit the question to get the answer $50N$? As you can see, it made you confused. By the way, there should be something going wrong with the drawing or question.

Comment: @Busi the answer of Gimusi is correct, we there is a force of $\vec{F}$ on the rope between the pulley and the ceiling and another force (the actual force you are exerting, the other one is a result of your force) of $\sin(37)\vec{F}$. This is exactly why you'd want to use such a pulley, you can decrease the amount of force you have to exert to lift a weight by quite a lot. In fact, the two forces, together balance the 80 $N$ while I only exert one times the force $F$. The magnitude of $F$ is then given by $F+F\sin(37)=80\;\;\implies F=50N$

Comment: However, the fact that everyone finds anohter answer. Totally, there are four different answers: $33.54$, $57.12$, $133.33N$ and $49.94$ How should I edit the question to get only one answer?

Comment: Can anyone reply my question?

Comment: @Busi Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

In the vertical direction we have that

$$F+F\sin 37° =80 \implies F=\frac{80}{1+\sin 37°}=49.94 N$$

[image]

Comment: How should I edit the question to get the answer $50N$? I'm getting too many answers differently.

Comment: @Busi Note that $$\frac{80}{1+\sin 37°}=49.94 N$$

Comment: Gimusi.Well done!

Comment: @PeterSzilas Hi Peter!  Thanks for your appreciation!

Comment: Yes but everyone finds anohter answer as mentioned. So, there should be something I'm missing while in the act of writing the question.

Comment: @Busi The only correct anwer is 49.94 N by equilibrium!